# Async WinInet fails with ERROR_IO_PENDING

Tags: python, windows-7, wininet

We have observed a WinInet problem in Windows 7. We see that in async. mode, when **InternetReadFile()** returns **ERROR_IO_PENDING**, sometimes it does not trigger a **INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED** event. I am sure that we are receving the full response correctly, because I have used Wireshark to capture the traffic. But the application using WinInet is not. We suspected that this problem is related with the way we use WinInet API, however, it turns out that we can even reproduce the issue with the async. WinInet example on MSDN. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc185684(v=vs.85).aspx)

I change the example to connect to my testing server. The testing server is just sending 20000 bytes of data, that's all. We see this behavior only on Win 7 (WinInet dll version WIN7_IE9_RTM.110308-0330). Here is the actual testing server application in Python just to show that there is nothing special about the server:

```
import time
from socket import *

ADDR = ("", 80)
BUFSIZE = 1024

serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serversock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversock.bind(ADDR)
serversock.listen(5)
t0 = time.time()
while 1: 
    print 'waiting for connection. previous transaction takes %0.3f secs' % (time.time()-t0)
    t0 = time.time()
    clientsock, addr = serversock.accept()
    print '...connected from:', addr
    data = clientsock.recv(BUFSIZE)
    print 'recv data:' + repr(data)    

    send_data = "A" * 20482
    send_data += "supo\r\n\r\n"
    clientsock.send(send_data)
```

Regards,